# force grails to treat a string parameter as collection of string

Tags: list, grails, parameters

In grails, I have a Controller that expects a 'options' parameter that is sent via POST that  can be a collection, i.e. 'options=A&options=B&options=C' which gets into grails, thanks to grails magic, as options = *Collection of String with value ['A','B','C']*.
Problem is, when the user only picks one option, then the parameter becomes string and not string[] (or List) and when doing options.each then each, by groovy magic, gets processed character by character... how can I force options to be string[] or List so options.each is applied correctly?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

In your action, you can always assume it as list like as follows:

> List options = params.list('options')

Comment: Thanks Amit, it just works! Just wondering, where is this in the Grails reference documentation?

Comment: it's here http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/single.html#6.1.12%20Simple%20Type%20Converters

Comment: It has been moved in the docs to http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/single.html#typeConverters

Comment: you can read a detailed explanation about the type conversion in parameters in this article https://mrhaki.blogspot.com/2010/02/grails-goodness-type-conversion-on.html